# Foreign key allowing values not present in the referenced field

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I've got a table created this way (simplified) :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[values](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [parentId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[values] ADD CONSTRAINT [x] FOREIGN KEY([parentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[values] ([id])
```

This table contains 3000 rows.

If I execute the following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM values
WHERE parentId IS NOT NULL
AND parentId NOT IN (SELECT id FROM values)
```

I get 800 results.

How is that even possible ?

When inserting data, the foreign key is effective, and I can't insert anything with a parentId that cannot be found in the table. But why the data already present is allowed to be incoherent ?

I suppose the foreign key was added with data already in the table, but at the time it was added, shouldn't it have been rejected for consistency reasons ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was the data inserted using `BULK INSERT` or some other way where the constraint was not checked? If so, the data may have been allowed through for performance reasons and you may have an *untrusted constraint*.

You can see all untrusted constraints with the following query:

```
SELECT name, OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName, 
    OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) AS ReferencedTableName
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE is_not_trusted = 1
```

---

After a bulk insert, you need to manually re-check and trust the constraints using `ALTER TABLE [values] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [x]` (or `ALTER TABLE [values] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL` to re-check and trust all constraints for the table).

Comment: I can only guess that the data was inserted that way. That must be the reason. But when I execute `ALTER TABLE [values] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [x]`, it fails (conflict with constraint FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE), and if I remove `WITH CHECK`, the command completes successfully, which makes no sense, given the incoherent data contained in the table...

Comment: I can only assume the same as well. Otherwise it is exactly as you say, the insert would fail due to the constraint.